# Django project: location of model definition used by multiple other models

Tags: django, django-models

Given separate applications for both movies and books, for instance, where would I define models / tables such as genre, which reference both movies and books?

Do I define it in whichever application I create first, and then reference that in the second?  That doesn't seem right at all, but I've not worked out a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A third, common application for "genre" makes the most sense.

Then movies and books both import this additional (common) application.

Comment: Hmm.  I guess this seems odd to have a separate application that doesn't really do anything, other than hold some common miscellaneous tables, but I'm really not familiar with how things are done in Django.  Thank you.

Comment: "seems odd"?  In what way?  It's a common design pattern used in a variety of contexts.  Common stuff is pulled out into a common module that's reused by other modules.  Why would Django models be any different?

Comment: I think it's owing to other tutorials that advocate each application being responsible for a certain "task."  I'm just a bit confused is all.  I'm not making a smooth transition from .NET MVC / Rails to Django at all...

Comment: @Withnail: "genre maintenance" is not a task?  I would think that it was.  Also, "each application being responsible for a certain "task"" is a good rule.  "Although practicality beats purity."  Zen of Python.  Koan 9.  It's okay to bend a rule.

Comment: I agree with S.Lott, it makes sense. Besides, if you later decide to have a genre detail view showing all the books and movies under that genre, you'll already have an application for it.

Comment: I like to think about an application structure in terms of URLs. Does /genres/sci-fi/ make sense? I think it does.